# html/css trouble with zooming

Tags: html, css, zooming

Please don't judge me i just stared developing websites and this is my first one.
here is my website and no matter what i set position to i cant make form or images stay on there place. when using static position i cant place one image on another. so what can i do ?

```
<style type="text/css">
.position
{
position:Relative;
top:-40px;
left: 5px;
width:13%;
height:13%;
}
.WidthFull
{
position: static;
z-index: 0;
width: 99.4%;
}
.FormPosition
{
position: Relative;
top:-80px;
right:-1070px;

}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<img alt="" class="WidthFull" src="img/main%20Head.png" />
<img alt="" class="position" src="img/Letters%20connic.png" />
<div class=FormPosition>
    <form id="login" method="post" action="index.php">
<input type="text" placeholder="Your Email" name="email" autofocus/>                                                     
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Password" name="email" autofocus />

        <button type="submit" style="width: 5%; height: 25px; border: 0;background: #209cf8; border-radius:5px"><font size="3.0";><b>Login</b></font>

                    </button>
        <span></span>
    </form>
 </div>



 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What program are you using to design? certainly not hand-coded

Comment: its hand coded by me:) i suck dont i

Answer (score 0):

Use like this 
outer side div property will be relative and inner image/div property will be absolute 
which one you want to show up side

```
<style type="text/css">
.position-relative{
    position:relative;
}
.position-absolute{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
```

z-index:10;
        }

```
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="position-relative">
<img alt="" class="WidthFull" src="img/main%20Head.png" />
<img alt="" class="position-absolute" src="img/Letters%20connic.png" />
</div>

 </body>
 </html>
```